# Non Latin (Hebrew) characters in a served JS file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm writing a NodeJS/Express server to handle an MS-Access database. The DB has table and column names in Hebrew. When I try to serve a JS file that contains any Hebrew text (e.g a query that references those tables and columns), the Hebrew text in the JS code is corrupted.

Everything works perfectly fine on the server side. Queries are executed with Hebrew names and Hebrew text is returned. Also, when the JSON results of the SQL query are sent to the client (browser), Hebrew is shown correctly. The only problem is the Javascript files in which the Hebrew text is corrupted.

Both server and client sides are on Windows 10.

.1 I tried converting the Hebrew column name from ANSII to Unicode, and manually implementing the Unicode content in the JS file stored on the server. 
.2 I tried converting the JS file to several encodings, including utf-8/utf8, Windows-1255 and ISO-8859-1. 
.3 On the Express server code, I added "res.charset = ''", where  was the ones mentioned above.

None of this worked.

This is the code in the JS file on the server: 
        $("#tbody").append("" + element['מספר רציף'] + "")

This is how it appears in the browser's debugger (Google Chrome): 
 $("#tbody").append("" + element['×ž×¡×¤×¨ ×¨×¦×™×£'] + "")

JSON file served by the server is fine on the browser side, if I manually check the JSON object from Chrome's debugger, it does contain the above Hebrew field.

Comment: Setting the encoding header to the respective value should be enough, you should not need to convert your files.

Comment: Can you post the express js code(s) that serve the working JSON and the broken Javascript files, please?

Comment: I did try to set the res.charSet property, but it made no difference.

Comment: This is the complete JS file served to the client: 
$.post("/DBData",{
    dataType : "openJobs"
}, function(res) {
    res = res.toString('utf-8')
    var resO = JSON.parse(res)
    resO.forEach(element => {
        $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + element['מספר רציף'] + "</td></tr>")
    });

})

And this is the server Express part, which serves the file: 
        app.get("/*.js", function(req,res) {
            res.writeHead("200",{'content-type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(fs.readFileSync(process.cwd() + "/client" + req.originalUrl).toString())
        })

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code with formatting instead of putting it in a comment